# boost::asio::write UNICODE

Tags: c++, boost, unicode, stream, boost-asio

I have the following code in ANSII:

```
boost::asio::streambuf buffer;
std::ostream oss(&buffer);

boost::asio::async_write(socket_, buffer,
    strand_.wrap(
    boost::bind(&Connection::handleWrite, shared_from_this(),
    boost::asio::placeholders::error)));
```

I need to convert it to UNICODE. I tried the following:

```
boost::asio::basic_streambuf<std::allocator<wchar_t>> buffer; 
std::wostream oss(&buffer); 

boost::asio::async_write(socket_, buffer,
    strand_.wrap(
    boost::bind(&Connection::handleWrite, shared_from_this(),
    boost::asio::placeholders::error)));
```

Is there a way to use async_write() in UNICODE?

Comment: Your code simply uses a wide character _type_. This is (mostly) orthogonal with character _encodings_...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to know what encoding your data is coming in as.

For example in my applications I know the unicode data is coming in as UTF-8, and so I use the normal `char` versions of the functions. I then need to treat the buffers as unicode utf-8 data - but everything is received / sent OK.

If you're using a different character encoding then you may (or may not) get better milage using a wide character version like you have tried.

Comment: If I receive Unicode in UTF-8, I don't lose any of the characters? If not, is there any advantage of using wI/O functions?

Comment: @Takashi-kun If you're working with UTF-8 there is no advantage to using the wide character versions, and plenty of disadvantages. UTF-8 is an 8-bit (char) based encoding.

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite across all the calls you are making here (having only gotten deeply into asio recently myself) but I know you can simply handle the data with a vector very simply.

So for example this is what i have done for reading a unicode file and transmitting over a posix socket:

```
// Open the file
std::ifstream is(filename, std::ios::binary);

std::vector<wchar_t> buffer;

// Get the file byte length
long start = is.tellg();
is.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
long end = is.tellg();
is.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

// Resize the vector to the file length
buffer.resize((end-start)/sizeof(wchar_t));
is.read((char*)&buffer[0], end-start);

// Write the vector to the pipe
boost::asio::async_write(output, boost::asio::buffer(buffer),
                         boost::bind(&FileToPipe::handleWrite, this));
```

The call to boost::asio::buffer(vector) is documented here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer/overload17.html